# How to return a zero on empty results when using SUM and GROUP BY on a Date range

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT dtStartTime
     , SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,dtStartTime,dtStopTime)) AS thisTimer 
FROM tblTimers 
WHERE dtStartTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' 
GROUP BY YEAR(dtStartTime), MONTH(dtStartTime)
```

This query is supposed to get the the total amount of minutes for all timers in each month between 2017-01-01 and 2018-12-31.  It does this just fine; however, it does not return a row for months with no timers.

Currently it outputs something like:

```
dtStartTime........ | thisTimer
2018-02-14 09:25:59 | 661
2018-03-27 13:46:00 | 98
2018-05-07 09:24:22 | 633
2018-06-10 06:59:10 | 87
2018-11-10 12:10:52 | 318
2018-12-02 09:16:33 | 804
```

But I want it to output something more like:

```
thisMonth. | thisTimer
2018-01-01 | 0
2018-02-01 | 661
2018-03-01 | 98
2018-04-01 | 0
2018-05-01 | 633
2018-06-01 | 87
2018-07-01 | 0
2018-08-01 | 0
2018-09-01 | 0
2018-10-01 | 0
2018-11-01 | 318
2018-12-01 | 804
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Question is asked before search with "MySQL calendar tables" on stackoverflow.. Or you can use a delivered table (subquery) or temporary table using this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623782/mysql-generate-each-date-from-date-range-list

Comment: what do you mean "no timer" may you please give me a row as example?

Comment: As in one row might have a datetime of '2018-06-10 06:59:10', but the next datetime is not until '2018-11-10 12:10:52', there are no rows with values for July through October; so, the query does not produce a result.  Also, I think Raymond's example might answer the question, but frankly, that question's answer is so poorly explained, I'm having trouble adapting it to my own issue so far.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I was hoping for a way to just do this in mySQL, but Application level parsing proved a lot more manageable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, there were many levels of complexity I truncated from the example I posted to simplify the question.  While Raymond's link was technically the right answer to this question as I asked it, it created all sorts of issues trying to get it to work properly inside my query as a whole, since that meathod itself was so complex and poorly documented.

Strawberry's suggestion to just do this application level was much more simple, and is probably the way I would suggest of most people who might find this question in the future.

Though the exact solution will vary by application language and the data format you need your sequence in, here is a simple PHP solution that can act as a starting point for anyone who needs one (you may need to add an extra loop for years that resets your $i if querying more than one year at a time):

```
if ($timerQuery->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $timerQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
        $thisDate = strtotime($row['dtStartTime']); // Convert string to php datetime.
        $thisMonth = date('n',$thisDate); // get month value
        if($i < 12){ 
            $i ++;
            While ($thisMonth != $i && $i <= 12) {
                $strMonths .= "0, "; // add empty value for missing months.
                $i ++;
            }
            if ($thisMonth == $i){
                $strMonths .= $row['thisTimer']. ", "; // add next recorded month's value.
            }
        } 
    }
    $strMonths = rtrim($strMonths, ', '); // remove trailing comma.
} else {
    $ctyr = "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0";
}
echo $ctyr;
```